# Adding Asset in Drools Business Central Workbench Fails

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, drools, drools-guvnor

I'm playing around with the [KIE Business Central Workbench](https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_wb.workbench) deployed in an air gap environment using their latest [docker image](https://quay.io/repository/kiegroup/business-central-workbench). My hope is to leverage it to give my customers the ability to  manage our rules logic (implemented in .drl files) themselves. I started a docker container created from an image I built using the image they provide above. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM  quay.io/kiegroup/business-central-workbench:latest
COPY settings.xml /opt/jboss/.m2/settings.xml
USER root
RUN chown jboss:jboss  /opt/jboss/.m2/settings.xml
USER jboss
```

The `settings.xml` listed above contains a mirror to our locally hosted nexus repository. I added this due to requests in the logs going to maven central which always failed. I then exec'ed into the container and added a user with the admin role, then hit http://localhost:8080/business-central per the second link above. I then added a space, then a project with the space, then attempted to create new assets within the project. Adding any kind of asset yielded the following error:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.default:artifact:jar:1.0.0
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:202)
        ... 101 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.default:artifact:pom:1.0.0 from/to (https://my.nexus.org/): Connection reset
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
        ... 103 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.default:artifact:pom:1.0.0 from/to (https://my.nexus.org/): Connection reset
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at deployment.business-central.war//org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 106 more
```

The name of this dependency (as well as its distinct absence of any artifact by that name [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)) makes me think this is some kind of KIE artifact which gets created on the fly. The only config change I made was to add the admin user via exec'ing into the container. I'm scratching my head as to why this doesn't seem to work out of the box. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are not overriding any KIE specific configuration when you are copying your `settings.xml` file?
Have you checked the original content of that file in the base docker image?

Comment: The only thing I override with the import of settings.xml is the repo mirror used as well as the location of my local repository. Based on the Docker image above, I know for sure the local repo isn't accessible to the resulting container, but I don't think that would matter